# how to convert string date time to int using python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I am doing data preprocessing, so I am trying to convert the date string format into an int, but I got an error, please help me how to convert it.

I have data like this :

```
0        Apr-12
1        Apr-12
2        Mar-12
3        Apr-12
4        Apr-12
```

I tried this :

```
d=df['d_date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%m%Y'))
```

I got an error.

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-134-173081812744> in <module>()
----> 1 d=test['first_payment_date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%m%Y'))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   4036             else:
   4037                 values = self.astype(object).values
-> 4038                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   4039 
   4040         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas\_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-134-173081812744> in <lambda>(x)
----> 1 d=test['first_payment_date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%m%Y'))

~\Anaconda3\lib\_strptime.py in _strptime_datetime(cls, data_string, format)
    563     """Return a class cls instance based on the input string and the
    564     format string."""
--> 565     tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
    566     tzname, gmtoff = tt[-2:]
    567     args = tt[:6] + (fraction,)

~\Anaconda3\lib\_strptime.py in _strptime(data_string, format)
    360     if not found:
    361         raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
--> 362                          (data_string, format))
    363     if len(data_string) != found.end():
    364         raise ValueError("unconverted data remains: %s" %

ValueError: time data 'Apr12' does not match format '%m%Y'
```

Comment: You need `%b-%y`. See [this](http://strftime.org/) for more info.

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df['d_date'],format='%b-%y')` expanding on what @harvpan says

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed & replaced with `datetime`).

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, You need to se `%b-%y` as `Apr` is `%b` and `12` is `%y`. Refer to [Python's strftime directives](http://strftime.org/) for more information. Once you convert to datetime objects, you can then convert them to UNIX.

df:

```
col
0   Apr-12
1   Apr-12
```

For int datetime,

```
pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(df['col'], format='%b-%y').values.astype(float)).div(10**9)
```

Output:

```
0    1.333238e+09
1    1.333238e+09
dtype: float64
```

Explanation:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['col'], format='%b-%y')
```

Outputs:

```
0   2012-04-01
1   2012-04-01
Name: col, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```